# How to get the path and file size of some Unity built-in assets?

Tags: unity-game-engine, plugins

### Background

I am developing a Unity editor plugin that enables users to send a selected image file to a REST API endpoint in the cloud for processing (e.g. adding transforms and optimizations). The plugin also shows a comparison of the selected image's details before and after processing (e.g. width/height/size before vs after).

The user selects the desired image through the following piece of code:

```
selected_texture = (Texture2D) EditorGUI.ObjectField(drawing_rect, selected_texture, typeof(Texture2D), false);
```

Once its selected, I can then get the respective file size by doing this:

```
file_size = new FileInfo(AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(selected_texture)).Length;
```

### Problem

This works for most textures selected, but I encounter an error when I choose a built-in Unity texture. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'Resources/unity_builtin_extra'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two built-in asset-librarys in Unity:

1. BuiltIn-Library in "Resources/unity_builtin_extra": contains UGUI sprite、Default-Material、Shader and so on.
2. BuiltIn-Library in "Library/unity default resources": contains built-in 3D mesh and OnGUI assets.

If you are using AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath, you will always get one or another path above.

To solve the problem, you need do something like below code:

```
public const string BuiltinResources = "Resources/unity_builtin_extra";
public const string BuiltinExtraResources = "Library/unity default resources";

public static bool IsBuiltInAsset(string assetPath)
{
    return assetPath.Equals(BuiltinResources) || assetPath.Equals(BuiltinExtraResources);
}

public static long GetTextureFileLength(Texture texture)
{
    string texturePath = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(texture);
    if (IsBuiltInAsset(texturePath))
    {
        /*
            * You can get all built-in assets by this way.
            * 
        var allAssets = AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath(BuiltinResources);
        var allExtraAssets = AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath(BuiltinExtraResources);
        */

        // not supportted
        // return -1;

        // using MemorySize
        return Profiler.GetRuntimeMemorySizeLong(texture);
    }
    else
    {
        return new FileInfo(texturePath).Length;
    }
}
```